# Routing in laravel to update the registry

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am trying to update a record but when passing the data, it throws me this error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

I understand that there are problems with routing but I'm unable to find what is causing this.

My form:

```
<form action="{{route('profesorControll.update', $datosProfesor->id)}}" method="POST">
```

My routing:

```
Route::resource('profesorControll', 'profesor\ProfesorController');
```

My controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $camposProfesor = array('nombre_profesor' => $request['nombre_profesor'], 'apellido_profesor' => $request['apellido_profesor'], 'documento_profesor' => $request['documento_profesor'], 'fecha_nacimiento_profesor' => $request['fecha_nacimiento_profesor'], 'telefono_profesor' => $request['telefono_profesor'], 'telefono_movil_profesor' => $request['telefono_movil_profesor'], 'correo_profesor' => $request['correo_profesor'], 'domicilio_profesor' => $request['domicilio_profesor'], 'institucion_id' => $request['idInstitucion']);
    $update = DB::table('profesor')->where('id', $id)->update($camposProfesor);
    Session::flash('mensaje_profesor', 'Profesor modificado correctamente');
    return redirect('Profesores/Editar/'. $id);
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in resource update method is called using the put method to use put method in your form add below

```
<form action="{{route('profesorControll.update', $datosProfesor->id)}}" method="POST">
  {{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

check here 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing